# How to accessing a document with two different keys in Pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

```
collection = database.collection
collection.insert_one({"_id": friendship_code, "test@gmail.com": "user_name", "second@gmail.com": "second_user_name"}).inserted_id
```

I wanted to do something like this.Then I would have reached this document in 2 ways.

```
collection.find_one({"test@gmail.com": "user_name"})
```

or

```
collection.find_one({"second@gmail.com": "second_user_name"})
```

But in the key name "." can't be.
*bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'test@test.com' must not contain '.'*

I can't write the code like this.

```
collection = database.collection
collection.insert_one({"_id": friendship_code, "user1": "test@gmail.com", "user2": "second@gmail.com"}).inserted_id
```

Because sometimes mails change places. When a mail is saved with another mail, it can be user1 or user2.

```
collection = database.collection
collection.insert_one({"_id": friendship_code, "user1": "second@gmail.com", "User2": "another@gmail.com"}).inserted_id
```

I can check this with the if blog in python but this is not a good approach.

```
if collection.find_one ({"user1": "second@gmail.com"}) or collection.find_one({"user2": "second@gmail.com"}):
```

I want to retrieve all "second@gmail.com" data from the collection, even though I don't know if it's user2 or user1.

Comment: Have you tried using the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html#or) operator to check them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing user1, user2, etc. store them as a users array, then your query is simpler:

```
collection.insert_one({"_id": friendship_code, "users": ["test@gmail.com", "second@gmail.com"]}).inserted_id
```

Then either of these queries will return the relevant record:

```
print(collection.find_one({"users": "test@gmail.com"}))
print(collection.find_one({"users": "second@gmail.com"}))
```